# How to force Elasticsearch "terms" query to be not_analyzed

Tags: search, elasticsearch, lucene, search-engine

I want to make exact matches ids in a doc field. I have mapped the fields to index them `not_analyzed` but it seems like in the query each term is tokenizde or at least lowercased. How do I make the query also `not_analyzed`? Using ES 1.4.4, 1.5.1, and 2.0.0

Here is a doc:

```
 {
    "_index": "index_1446662629384",
    "_type": "docs",
    "_id": "Cat-129700",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
       "similarids": [
          "Cat-129695",
          "Cat-129699",
          "Cat-129696"
       ],
       "id": "Cat-129700"
    }
 }
```

Here is a query:

```
{
    "size": 10,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [{
                "terms": {
                    "similarids": ["Cat-129695","Cat-129699","Cat-129696"]
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

The query above does not work. If I remove caps and dashes from the doc ids it works. I can't do that for many reasons. Is there a way to make the similarids `not_analyzed` like the doc fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, all you need to do is set `"index":"not_analyzed"` on the `"similarids"` in your mapping. If you have that setting correct already, then there is something else going on that isn't apparent from what you posted (the [`"terms"` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) doesn't do any analysis on your search terms). You may want to check your mapping to make sure it is set up the way you think.

To test it, I set up a simple index like this:

```
PUT /test_index
{
   "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 1
   },
   "mappings": {
      "doc": {
         "properties": {
            "id": {
               "type": "string",
               "index": "not_analyzed"
            },
            "similarids": {
               "type": "string",
               "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Then added your document:

```
PUT /test_index/doc/1
{
   "similarids": [
      "Cat-129695",
      "Cat-129699",
      "Cat-129696"
   ],
   "id": "Cat-129700"
}
```

And your query works just fine.

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "size": 10,
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "should": [
            {
               "terms": {
                  "similarids": [
                     "Cat-129695",
                     "Cat-129699",
                     "Cat-129696"
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
...
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 0.53148466,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 0.53148466,
            "_source": {
               "similarids": [
                  "Cat-129695",
                  "Cat-129699",
                  "Cat-129696"
               ],
               "id": "Cat-129700"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I used ES 2.0 here, but it shouldn't matter which version you use. Here is the code I used to test:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/562ccda28dfaed2717b43739696b88ea861ad690

Comment: Yes you are exactly correct. I had accidentally disabled that mapping so I thought it was in but it wasn't. Thanks